# Why does Ubuntu deem 16.04 un-affected by CVE-2017-16995(Kernel Privilege Escalation) while it's not?

Tags: ubuntu, cve, privilege-escalation, kernel

In both current OVAL definition and [CVE Tracker](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2017/CVE-2017-16995.html), it says for Ubuntu 16.04

> While related to the CVE in some way, the 'linux' package in xenial is
>   not affected.

But I have tested many kernel versions in Default 16.04 installation. They are certainly affected by this vulnerability. and after I apply the mitigation, the exploit no longer works.

Is there any reason behind describing them as unaffected?

Comment: Did you checked it is compiled in (and accessible by user mode?). RHEL did also specify they are not affected: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1528518

Comment: @eckes I tested by exploit.the vulnerability as a normal user with no extra privilege. isn't this enough?

Comment: It probably is. What kernel are you seeing? 4.4.0-116.140? Strange enough the CVE tracker talks about 4.15 and I have no idea what DNE means :) https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2017/CVE-2017-16995.html

Comment: It is short for "Does Not Exist"., however there is limited information about what does not exist, popular understanding is "Vulnerable Component Does Not Exist", correct me if I'm wrong.